# Nullpointer in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

I get message from OCR and post it by `rxjava` like this.

```java
Disposable disposable = Observable.just(OCR())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.MainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(schedulers.newThread())
                    .flatMap(new Function<Rsult,ItemsBean>(){
                        ............
                    })
                    .subscribe(new Consumer(){
                        ............
                    })
```

OCR() itself get message from server and return type is an entity,code here

```
public static Result OCR(){
ImageClient imageClient = new ImageClient();
String result = imageClient.OCR(**,**,**);//network
Result resultEntity = gson.fromJson(result);
return resultEntity;
```

}

but it is null instead,so i tried to use this instead,code:

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.just(imageClient.OCR(**,**,**))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.MainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(schedulers.newThread())
                    .map(new Function(){
                        ............此处省略
                    })
                    .flatMap(new Function<Rsult,ItemsBean>(){
                        ............此处省略
                    })
                    .subscribe(new Consumer(){
                        ............此处省略
                    })
```

and throws network in mainThread exception,i wonder what is the correct way to use it,Thanks.

Comment: so, if I get it correctly, OCR() is returning a null value? If so, is it correct that OCR() gives you a null value?

Comment: How is `OCR` implemented?

Comment: just updated,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `Observable.just` will execute the argument at the moment it is passed through. and due to `imageClient.OCR(**,**,**)` makes a call to the network. You are getting the exception.

To prevent this you have to envelop the execution and then subscribe to:

A way to achieve this is with:

```
Observable.fromCallable { imageClient.OCR(**,**,**) }
```

See also [Creating Observables doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables)